# Siebel - Update Field BUT the Field's Name contains "." (Dot)

Tags: siebel

Good Evening.

I have the following problem. 
Within a Workflow I am making an "Update". 
If I do it on fields that do NOT have "." (DOT) in the name makes perfect. 
But if I do it on fields have "." (DOT) in the name, does not perform the update in the field. 
I understand that this is because it is confused with the "Dot Notation".

Do You know how to do an UPDATE on a field that has the name "." (DOT)?
Thank you so much!

Comment: It may not work, but... have you tried using the dot notation? :) Maybe if there is already a dot to separate the buscomp from the field name, it won't get confused with the field name's dot?

Comment: AJPerez Gracias por la Respuesta. Asi es, se está confundiendo el nombre del campo con DOT Notation. Entonces.....Como hago para realizar el UPDATE cuando el NOMBRE del campo tiene un "PUNTO" ??

Comment: Jperez Thanks for the response. Yes, it is mistaking the field name with the notation DOT. So ..... How Perform UPDATE When The Name field has a "DOT" in his name ?? -